# Google Audit Question

Tags: javascript, html, audit

> The following external CSS files were
>   included after an external JavaScript
>   file in the document head. To ensure
>   CSS files are downloaded in parallel,
>   always include external CSS before
>   external JavaScript. 1 inline script
>   block was found in the head between an
>   external CSS file and another
>   resource. To allow parallel
>   downloading, move the inline script
>   before the external CSS file, or after
>   the next resource.

My HTML is:

```
<head>

    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="gStyle.css" />        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gMain.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       // Your chart object(s)
        var myChart;

        // Function to hold all chart creation
        function initCharts() {

            myChart = new ganttChart("chart1");

            myChart.gAddBar("Dynamic!", "22/3/2010", "3/4/2010");

            myChart.gLoadData("Going to the shop*4/3/2010*19/3/2010*Watching TV*9/3/2010*23/3/2010*Watching TV*1/3/2010*23/3/2010*Watching TV*18/3/2010*28/3/2010*END INPUT*1/3/2010*9/3/2010");

            myChart.gDraw();

            myChart.gChangeBarColour(1, "#dd2200");
            myChart.gChangeBarColour(2, "#9900ee");
            myChart.gChangeBarColour(3, "#00dd00");
            myChart.gChangeBarColour(4, "#ffbb00");
            myChart.gChangeBarColour(5, "#00aa99");

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="initCharts()">




    <div id="chart1" class="gContainer">     


    </div>

    <div id="db"></div>

</body>
```

Is it getting confused between the body inline script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inspect the page elements. Probably your Chrome extensions are dynamically adding scripts to the page in HEAD.

Comment: For me it was the Google Maps API JS that dynamically adds extra <script> blocks before the end of the <head>

Answer (score 1):

I think that when javascript is downloaded the browser must wait to get it all and then run it - this stops it going to the next line directly and getting it. I guess styles all get downloaded and then computed down to inheritance position and importance etc...so they can download in parallel.

This kind of thing is hard to regulate in a CMS with components that load their own style and js.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Google Analytics library inserted scripts before the rest of mine.